# How can a method have different number of arguments?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set, hashset

I am trying to use hashmaps where the **key** is a persons name,`String` and the **value** is a `HashSet` that contains their favourite types of food:
this is what I have come up with:

```
public void addMapEntry(string1, string2, string3)
{  
       favFood = new HashSet<>();
       favFod.add(string1);
       favFod.add(string2);
       favFod.add(string3);
}
```

This feels VERY clunky and not a good way to do it at all, what if there are less that 3 favorite food? or more?
What is a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at using varargs: (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/method_varargs1.htm)

Comment: Pass a `Collection<String>`, and call `favFood.addAll(collection)`. Varargs have their place, but they have limitations (e.g. gets messy with generics; you can only have 1 varargs parameter; they have to appear at the end of the param list). Effective Java 2nd ed Item 42 is entitled "Use varargs judiciously".

Comment: A bit left field but you can also take a look at Guava's multimaps for the whole problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using **[*varargs*](https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs)** would probably be the best in this case.

> The **[*varargs*](https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs)** allows the method to accept zero or multiple arguments.

```
public void addMapEntry(String key, String... foods)
{      
       ...
       ...
       favFood = new HashSet<>();
       for (String item : foods) {
            favFood.add(item);
       }
       ...
       ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could create an `ArrayList`, add all the strings into it then pass it into the `addMapEntry` method.